# Android: path of assets folder for File()?

Tags: java, android, directory, assets

I have some files in the assets folder of my project, and I want to list them, so I put this in my code:

```
File dir = new File("com.packagename/assets/fonts");
File[] fileList = dir.listFiles();
```

Which path should I put to make it work?
I want it so users could install new fonts (I don`t know how to do this yet) so I need to list all the fonts in the folder, including post-installed fonts. If there is any other solutions, please share.

Comment: What language is this written in? It looks like Java...

Comment: i'm sorry i hadn't specified that it's an Android project

Comment: You will always get better results with a descriptive question (i.e. using proper tags, using code in your question, and including the error message if there is one). Also if someone solves your problem you should accept their answer by clicking the checkmark under the upvote/downvote arrows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assets and resources are accessible using file:///android_asset and file:///android_res.

But in this case you will want to do something like this :

```
Resources res = getResources()
AssetManager am = res.getAssets();
String fileList[] = am.list(dirFrom);

if (fileList != null) {   
   for ( int i = 0;i<fileList.length;i++) {
        Log.d("",fileList[i]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the resources part is required?? i did something similar without it and it worked

Comment: It's a directory string such as "images" where you're searching for your assets.