# How to access files (such as assets folder) of other apps in android?

Tags: android

I'm very new to android development and to the mobile programming world (now experimenting with Eclipse), and I would like to access other apps folder assets for **educational purposes**.

e.g. to learn how a specific app is arranging it's resources; is it a native java app or is it based on WebView with HTML5; etc...

Should I need to root my device? is this can be done without rooting?

I have downloaded SD Maid (on my non-rooted device) and I can't find anything "useful" on my device becouse I suspect I have no access to the apps folders.

Comment: you can keep your files in assets folder and can access them through code by providing path to your assetfolder...for eg... i used it with database...OutputStream databaseOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
     "/data/data/com.ioc/databases/IOC_Database.sqlite");

Comment: You can refer to this link also...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372500/android-path-of-assets-folder-for-file

Answer (score 2):

Download an Apk and copy it to windows, with winrar extract the .apk file. With this you can only get assets folder items and drawable items, no coding files. Without Rooting you can't view data of other apps.

Comment: I know I can extract the APK as zip, BUT, How can I download the APK from the Play store?

Comment: use apkshare app from playstore and in that app you can find list of all apps, and you get an option for share or backup. go ahead and do research.

Comment: Looks very promising! I'll check it out now. Also, please explain what do you mean by "no coding files"?

Comment: I have downloaded ApkShare. I backed-up the Apps I needed to test, and then extracted them in Windows and inspected them. However, all the XML files (including the layout) are *Binary*. Is this by design? How can I view the XML files in normal state. (p.s. I haven't tried to open them with Eclipse yet).

Comment: Hope-so you looking for decompiling apk and tries to read the app coding, so go a head and read this webpage, you'll find what you want. There are lot of ways but i'm using the solution of 1st webpage below here. http://manijshrestha.wordpress.com/2012/02/08/decompiling-an-android-apk-file-to-view-the-underlying-code/
http://codexplo.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/how-to-decompile-android-apk-to-java-source-code/

Comment: Thanks m8! Your answer gave me a great push, and I found the apktool with aapt - I haven't seen any JAVA sources though... I'll check your new links ASAP! as for your rep, I bet someone with knowledge like yours will regain it in no time :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are interested in the layouts, there is a useful option in the Developer options (at least on the Nexus 4, android 4.4) - `Show layout bounds` - then you can see the bounds of every layout that is used.